# Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Object?>?' in type cast

Tags: ios, flutter, sharedpreferences

The above error is thrown on this line.

```
await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

It works fine in android device but giving error in ios device.